# Countdown script

Tags: javascript, countdown, momentjs

I have a countdown script which is only showing hours minutes and seconds like this: 29:30 54

But I want to have it like this 1 day and 4:30:54

This is the script what do I have to change I tried several things but it want work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        window.setInterval(function(){
        var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var then = "<?php echo $d['expiration'] ?>";
        var ms = moment(then,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
        var d = moment.duration(ms);
        var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
        if(d.asHours() > 96) {
            then = moment().endOf('day');
            ms = moment(then,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
            d = moment.duration(ms);
            s = Math.floor(d()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
        } 
        if(d.asHours() <= 0) {
            s = "Verlopen";
        }
        $( ".countdown_container_1" ).html( s );
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
<div class="countdown_container countdown_container_1">0:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Oh come on.. It's just a matter of divisions..

Comment: Basic math this, you learned this in high school. Divide the hours by 24, round it down, and set the remainder as hours.

Comment: Thank you for you answers but i dont know anything about javascript .

Answer (score 0):

Solution [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/):

```
d = moment.duration(Math.floor(d.asHours()), 'hours').humanize();
```

This should convert your hours into a more human readable string.

Doing it using plain JavaScript.

```
var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
var days =  Math.floor(hours / 24) //convert to days.
hours = hours - days*24; //subtract the amount of hours from the total amount of hours that are full days.
var s = days + " day(s) and " + hours + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```

And as a total solution:

```js
$(function() {

var then = "2015/03/7"; //changed this to make the snippet work. Change it back to the php code for your production site.
window.setInterval(function(){
 var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
 
 var ms = moment(then,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
 var d = moment.duration(ms);
 if(d.asHours() > 96) {
  then = moment().endOf('day');
  ms = moment(then,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
  d = moment.duration(ms);
 }
 var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
 var days =  Math.floor(hours / 24) //convert to days.
 hours = hours - days*24; //subtract the amount of hours from the total amount of hours that are full days.
 var s = days + " day(s) and " + hours + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");   

 if(d.asHours() <= 0) {
  s = "Verlopen";
 }
 $( ".countdown_container_1" ).html( s );
}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>


<div class="countdown_container countdown_container_1">0:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but were do i have to put it in the script and i think some things should be deleted?

Comment: @Andre Total solution added.

Comment: Thank you mouser but stil not working.
Maybe its in the countdown script wich is in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0

/*
countdown is a simple jquery plugin for countdowns

Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
and GPL-3.0 (http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0) licenses.

@source: http://github.com/rendro/countdown/
@autor: Robert Fleischmann
@version: 1.0.1
*/


(function() {

  (function($) {
    $.countdown = function(el, options) {
      var getDateData,
        _this = this;
      this.el = el;
      this.$el = $(el);
      this.$el.data("countdown", this);
      this.init = function() {
        _this.options = $.extend({}, $.countdown.defaultOptions, options);
        if (_this.options.refresh) {
          _this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            return _this.render();
          }, _this.options.refresh);
        }
        _this.render();
        return _this;
      };
      getDateData = function(endDate) {
        var dateData, diff;
        endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date) ? _this.options.date : new Date(_this.options.date));
        diff = (endDate - Date.parse(new Date)) / 1000;
        if (diff <= 0) {
          diff = 0;
          if (_this.interval) {
            _this.stop();
          }
          _this.options.onEnd.apply(_this);
        }
        dateData = {
          years: 0,
          days: 0,
          hours: 0,
          min: 0,
          sec: 0,
          millisec: 0
        };
        if (diff >= (365.25 * 86400)) {
          dateData.years = Math.floor(diff / (365.25 * 86400));
          diff -= dateData.years * 365.25 * 86400;
        }
        if (diff >= 86400) {
          dateData.days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
          diff -= dateData.days * 86400;
        }
        if (diff >= 3600) {
          dateData.hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
          diff -= dateData.hours * 3600;
        }
        if (diff >= 60) {
          dateData.min = Math.floor(diff / 60);
          diff -= dateData.min * 60;
        }
        dateData.sec = diff;
        return dateData;
      };
      this.leadingZeros = function(num, length) {
        if (length == null) {
          length = 2;
        }
        num = String(num);
        while (num.length < length) {
          num = "0" + num;
        }
        return num;
      };
      this.update = function(newDate) {
        _this.options.date = newDate;
        return _this;
      };
      this.render = function() {
        _this.options.render.apply(_this, [getDateData(_this.options.date)]);
        return _this;
      };
      this.stop = function() {
        if (_this.interval) {
          clearInterval(_this.interval);
        }
        _this.interval = null;
        return _this;
      };
      this.start = function(refresh) {
        if (refresh == null) {
          refresh = _this.options.refresh || $.countdown.defaultOptions.refresh;
        }
        if (_this.interval) {
          clearInterval(_this.interval);
        }
        _this.render();
        _this.options.refresh = refresh;
        _this.interval = setInterval(function() {
          return _this.render();
        }, _this.options.refresh);
        return _this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this npart was alreadyh enough. Thank you

var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
var days =  Math.floor(hours / 24) //convert to days.
hours = hours - days*24; //subtract the amount of hours from the total amount of hours that are full days.
var s = days + " day(s) and " + hours + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");